# How to Reindex with new Java Api in ES 6.4?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

There are exists old way of re-indexing using `TransportClient` but as it will be deprecated in ES7 what is the new way of reindexing using `RestHighLevelClient` ?

```
BulkByScrollResponse response = ReindexAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
    .destination("target_index")
    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("category", "xzy")) 
    .get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the docs this will be available in the next minor release (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/java-rest-high-document-reindex.html)

maybe you should issue a http reindex request to the cluster: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-reindex.html